# Trying regex pattern on greylog search

Tags: regex, graylog2

Hej,

I'm trying to query graylog for any message not containing something that would match the regex pattern:

```
     (\\w+-)*\\d+
```

For example:
some-article-x-12397

But normal regex seems not to be working for graylog. The help page doesn't give me enough information. ( http://support.torch.sh/help/kb/graylog2-web-interface/the-search-bar-explained )

Comment: The regex itself is `(\w+-)*\d+` but in some languages when you write the string you have to escape the backslash. Don't know graylog, but are you sure it requires you to double the backslashes in the regex string?

Comment: I already tried all variations of that.

Comment: @zx81 All of these: && || : \ / + - ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? have to be escaped in graylog

Comment: That was just a troubleshooting idea, sounds like you have already tried it and it doesn't work. :)

Answer (score 2):

I do not find anywhere that Graylog2 accepts regular expressions in its Search (it does for definig streams, etc.).
It just states:

> Use ? to replace a single character or * to replace zero or more
>   characters

Source: https://www.graylog.org/documentation/general/queries/

Answer (score 0):

> "All of these: && || : \ / + - ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? have to be escaped in graylog"

If you're supposed to escape all of those characters then your expression should look like this:

```
\(\\w\+\-\)\*\\d\+
```

---

I escaped those characters with the following:

**Pattern:**

```
([&|:\/\\+!(){}[\]^"~*?-])
```

**Substitution:**

```
\\\1
```

[**See for yourself**](http://regex101.com/r/zO4qE4)

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work either. I think graylog is a bit "special" when it comes to regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like you don't need to add the / at the beginning or end to denote the beginning and end of the regex.

So `(\bError\b)\s+(\bEmail\b)\s+(\bsent\b)` seems valid but `/(\bError\b)\s+(\bEmail\b)\s+(\bsent\b)/g` is not.